# Want to do an action by a link created by jquery itself

Tags: jquery, onclick

I dont know how to put my question here, I will just copy my code here, better that will explain perfectly, i have a p tag with class 'a'

```
<p class="a">Test</p>
```

the jquery i am using here is--

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){


    $('.a').click(function(){
   (jQuery('<a href="home" class="b">Super Test</a>')).insertAfter('.a');

 return false;
 });



$('.b').on('click', function(){
    alert('hai');
    return false;
});
});
```

Ok, when i click on p tag with class 'a' it successfully inserts a link with class 'b', here What I want is If i click on link with class 'b' I want to do something. I dont know is it possible or I am asking a foolish question, any how is it possible then please help me with the solution or if there is any  other way to achieve this, share that please. thank you. because actually i want to overcome this type situation in my project, that actually gets some links through ajax, then if customer click on those links (created through ajax) want to display something using ajax itself.

Comment: 4th time today.. event delegation. http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: Asked hundred times a week...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is working, you have to add `e.preventDefault()` to prevent the default event from occuring. If you still have the same problem, if you're using an older version of jquery 
use `live()` instead of `on()`.

> .live() is deprecated, and .on() was not introduced until version 1.7.

**Edit:**
if you're using a new version of jQuery just use something like that:

```
    $('.a').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.a').after(' <a href="home" class="b">Super Test</a> ');
    });


$(document).on('click', '.b', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            alert('hai');
});
```

**Working Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/ouadie/Hw9Qa/

Comment: Now why would you say that?

Comment: I just updated my solution, Maybe he's using an older version of jQuery

Comment: `live()` removed from 1.9.1, just use `$(document).on('click', '.b', function(e) { e.preventDefault(); alert('hai'); });` it should work, here is a working example http://jsfiddle.net/ouadie/Hw9Qa/

Comment: thanx buddy.....I had a little confusion with selecting the parent element, thats why the problem was.... now its working

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to delegate `.b` using `.on()`:

```
$(document).on('click', '.b', function() {
  // your code
});
```

Replace document with an element which is closest to where `b` will reside, and exists on the page when the DOM is loaded. This will prevent the click event propagating right the way up to the `document`

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `.append()` and you need to add prevent default for the anchor tag action like

```
$('.a').on('click',function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   jQuery('.a').append('<a href="home" class="b">Super Test</a>');      
});
```

and in delagate method you can give like

```
$(document).on('click','.a',function(){
   e.preventDefault();
   jQuery('.a').append('<a href="home" class="b">Super Test</a>');      
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible and your code is working.
Just add `preventDefault` inside click method

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on('click', '.b', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('hai');
    return false;
});
```

[jQuery API **.on()**](http://api.jquery.com/on/)